# In Temeraire, where does the captain sit during flight?

Tags: temeraire

I've started reading the *[Temeraire](https://www.goodreads.com/series/43272-temeraire)* series, by Naomi Novik, and have reached the point where they describe the crew. I'm having trouble visualising the crew and captain's positions during flight; where do crew members typically "start"? The captain seems to have no trouble speaking both to his dragon and to the rest of the crew, but Temeraire is a little too big for me to imagine that being easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially (and while the dragon is small enough) Laurence flies using a saddle and harness, stationed slightly behind the wings.

> Laurence shifted his weight and pulled against the straps wrapped
> snugly around his thighs and calves; they did not give, nor did the
> main part of the harness, and he remained stable in his perch atop
> Temeraire’s back, just behind the wings. “No, Tom, it won’t do, and
> you know it; this is not a fishing-boat, and you cannot spare the men.
> We might very well meet a Frenchman one of these days, and then where
> would we be?” He leaned forward and patted Temeraire’s neck; the
> dragon’s head was doubled back, observing the proceedings with
> interest.
>
> <sub><sup>[His Majesty's Dragon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28876.His_Majesty_s_Dragon)</sup></sub>

Assuming Téméraire is rigged out in much the same way as other dragons, the captain would be at the fore of the "belly rigging", basically a large hammock slung underneath the dragon, stretching from the neck to the stomach, allowing a view of the ground.

> Laurence followed them outside, and was witness, for the first time,
> to the operation of a full aerial crew. Temeraire and he both watched
> with interest from the side as Laetificat stood patiently under the
> swarming ensigns, who ran up and down her sides as easily as they hung
> below her belly or climbed upon her back. The boys were raising up two
> canvas enclosures, one above and one below; these were like small,
> lopsided tents, framed with many thin and flexible strips of metal.
> The front panels which formed the bulk of the tent were long and
> sloped, evidently to present as little resistance to the wind as
> possible, and the sides and back were made of netting.
>
> The ensigns all looked to be below the age of twelve; the midwingmen
> ranged more widely, just as aboard a ship, and now four older ones
> came staggering with the weight of a heavy leather-wrapped chain they
> dragged in front of Laetificat. The dragon lifted it herself and laid
> it over her withers, just in front of the tent, and the ensigns
> hurried to secure it to the rest of the harness with many straps and
> smaller chains.
>
> Using this strap, **they then slung a sort of hammock made of chain
> links beneath Laetificat’s belly.** Laurence saw his own chest tossed
> inside along with a collection of other bags and parcels; he winced at
> the haphazard way in which the baggage was stowed, and was doubly
> grateful that he had been careful in his packing: he was confident
> they might turn his chest completely about a dozen times without
> casting his things into disarray.
>
> A large pad of leather and wool, perhaps the thickness of a man’s arm,
> was laid on top of all, then **the hammock’s edges were drawn up and
> hooked to the harness as widely as possible, spreading the weight of
> the contents and pressing them close to the dragon’s belly.** Laurence
> felt a sense of dissatisfaction with the proceedings; he privately
> thought he would have to find a better arrangement for Temeraire, when
> the time came.
>
> However, the process had one significant advantage over naval
> preparations: from beginning to end it took fifteen minutes, and then
> they were looking at a dragon in full light-duty rig. Laetificat
> reared up on her legs, shook out her wings, and beat them half a dozen
> times; the wind was strong enough to nearly stagger Laurence, but the
> assembled baggage did not shift noticeably.
>
> “All lies well,” Laetificat said, dropping back down to all fours; the
> ground shook with the impact.
>
> “Lookouts aboard,” Portland said; four ensigns climbed on and took up
> positions at the shoulders and hips, above and below, hooking
> themselves on to the harness. “Topmen and bellmen.” Now two groups of
> eight midwingmen climbed up, one going into the tent above, the other
> below: Laurence was startled to perceive how large the enclosures
> really were; they seemed small only by virtue of comparison with
> Laetificat’s immense size.
>
> The crews were followed in turn by the twelve riflemen, who had been
> checking and arming their guns while the others rigged out the gear.
> Laurence noticed Lieutenant Dayes leading them, and frowned; he had
> forgotten about the fellow in the rush. Dayes had offered no apology;
> now most likely they would not see one another for a long time.
> Perhaps it was for the best; Laurence was not sure that he could have
> accepted the apology, after hearing Temeraire’s story, and as it was
> impossible to call the fellow out, the situation would have been
> uncomfortable to say the least.
>
> The riflemen having boarded, Portland walked a complete circuit around
> and beneath the dragon. “Very good; ground crew aboard.” The handful
> of men remaining climbed into the belly-rigging and strapped
> themselves in; only then did Portland himself ascend, Laetificat
> lifting him up directly. **He repeated his inspection on the top,
> maneuvering around on the harness with as much ease as any of the
> little ensigns, and finally came to his position at the base of the
> dragon’s neck.** “I believe we are ready; Captain Laurence?
>
> <sub><sup>[His Majesty's Dragon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28876.His_Majesty_s_Dragon)</sup></sub>

Comment: As usual, the book covers bear no relation to what's actually inside the book; https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1363033347l/142652.jpg, https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1249759166l/6688365.jpg, etc

Comment: Thank you! I reread that section to try and find out but I missed the line about the captain. (and the cover images are very silly; they also all seem to show Western-style dragons!)